# Recorrido de valores en columnas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y deseo recorrer cada linea de la columna "CO_tin_no" para consultarlo con un webservice

```
item=[]

for nit in mydataset_df.CO_tin_no:
    nit = mydataset_df.CO_tin_no
    url = 'http://www.rues.org.co/RM/ConsultaNIT_json'

    headers, payload = {
            'Content-Type':
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        }, {'txtNIT': nit}
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload, timeout=4)
    if r.json().get('rows', False):
        res = r.json()['rows'][0]
        legal_name = res['razon_social'].title()
        item.append(legal_name)
        #print item
        mydataset_df['legal_name'] = item

    else:
        response = 'no se encuentra el nit o cc ->'
        mydataset_df['legal_name'] = response
        #print response, nit

mydataset_df['legal_name'] = item
```

Esta función se detiene cuando no consigue un registro en el webservice y no continua la validación.

El error de respuesta es:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Creo que puede ser más eficiente (o al menos más sencillo) iterar directamente sobre los valores de la columna, en lugar de hacerlo sobre un índice. Así: `for nit in mydataset_df.Co_tin_no:`

Comment: El error es "Length of values does not match length of index" la pregunta es: como lo resuelvo?